# vagrant ssh failed since the network segment changed

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I am using vagrant for a long time.

Recently our office has moved to a new place, the network segment has changed from 192.168.10.x to 192.168.1.x.

Since then, the command `vagrant ssh` failed. And when I tried `vagrant up` again,

it shows

```
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
default: SSH username: vagrant
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
```

But when I turned off the wireless in my OSX. All vagrant commands works fine.
And it failed again when I turned on the network.

Could some one give me some hint to solve this issue?
Thanks.